# Unexpected behavior of class scoped fixture when calling a class scoped parametrized fixture in Pytest

Tags: pytest

I have a test in a class with parametrized indirect `class` scoped fixture. When another regular `class` scoped fixture is calling the parametrized fixture, its execution seems to be more `function` scoped. Meaning the regular fixture is called again, for every test method. When removing the parametrized fixture call, it is executed once per class as expected.

I am aware of fixture life cycle as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750390/unexpected-behavior-of-class-scoped-fixture-in-pytest), but I am not exiting the class. What I am missing here?

pytest-7.0.1, pytest-asyncio-0.17.2

Code:

```
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='class')
async def some_fixture(request, iteration):  # <---- when not using 'iteration', works as expected
    print(f'-some_fixture-{request.scope}-start')
    yield
    print(f'-some_fixture-{request.scope}-end')

@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope='class')
async def iteration(self, request):
    print(f'-iteration-{request.scope}-start')
    yield request.param
    print(f'-iteration-{request.scope}-end')

@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1), indirect=True)  # <---- tried adding scope='class', no success
@pytest.mark.asyncio
class Something:
    async def test_something(self, iteration, some_fixture):
        print(test_body)
```

Output:

```
test_foo.py::test_something[1] -iteration-class-start
-some_fixture-class-start
-test_body
PASSED
test_foo.py::test_something[2] -some_fixture-class-end  # <---- why it end here?
-iteration-class-end
-iteration-class-start
-some_fixture-class-start  # <--- called twice
-test_body
PASSED                                                                                                                                                     
-some_fixture-class-end
-iteration-class-end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for parametrized fixtures. A fixture can be directly parametrized (via the `params` argument in the fixture decorator) or indirectly parametrized by a test (as shown in the question). Both cases are semantically equivalent, and mean that a fixture will be called with different parameters and yield different outcomes. Therefore the fixture has to be evaluated for each parameter separately - you can think of this as a separate fixture for each parameter instead of a single fixture.

The same is true if a fixture (as `some_fixture` in your example) is "derived" from a parametrized fixture - it will also be parametrized, as a separate outcome is calculated for each parameter. To illustrate this, you can add the parameter to the fixture in the output. Here is a slightly changed example to demonstrate this:

```py
ITERATIONS = 2

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def some_fixture(request, iteration):
    print(f'-some_fixture-{request.scope}-{iteration}-start')
    yield
    print(f'-some_fixture-{request.scope}-{iteration}-end')

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def iteration(request):
    print(f'-iteration-{request.scope}-{request.param}-start')
    yield request.param
    print(f'-iteration-{request.scope}-{request.param}-end')

@pytest.mark.parametrize('iteration', range(1, ITERATIONS + 1),
                         indirect=True)
class TestSomething:
    def test_something(self, some_fixture):
        print("test_something")

    def test_something_else(self, some_fixture):
        print("test_something_else")
```

I have removed the async part, as it is not relevant for the question, added the parameter to the fixture output and added a second test in the class (also adapted the test names to be recognized by pytest).

The output for this is:

```
-iteration-class-1-start
-some_fixture-class-1-start
PASSED test_something
PASSED test_something_else
-some_fixture-class-1-end
-iteration-class-1-end
-iteration-class-2-start
-some_fixture-class-2-start
PASSED test_something
PASSED test_something_else
-some_fixture-class-2-end
-iteration-class-2-end
```

Note that the fixture is called only once for each parameter, even if it is used multiple times (in this case twice in the 2 tests). As you can see, it indeed behaves like a class fixture, if fixtures with different parameters are seen as different fixtures (as they should).